# SQL выборка по последнему ID для каждого человека

Tags: sql, select

Есть таблица в которой записывается на каком датчике фиксируются люди и время этой регистрации. Поле ID имеет автоувеличение для каждой следующей записи на 1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно с помощью поля ID получить последний датчик (ID_SENSOR) для каждого человека (ID_PEOPLE).
Пробовал через max(ID) и группировать по ID_PEOPLE, но выдает неправильный результат.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: какая СУБД и версия? в целом тут row_number по id обратно по человеку и фильтрация первых строк. Если нет оконных, то можете сначала группировку по человеку с max(id) а потом заджйонить на это саму таблицу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так попроще будет

```
select *
from(
  select *
      ,row_number()over(partition by id_people order by id desc) rn_id
  from test
  ) t
where rn_id=1
```

Или вариант для упорядочения по времени

```
select *
from(
  select *
      ,row_number()over(partition by id_people order by s_date desc,s_time desc) rn_time
  from test
  ) t
where rn_time=1
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL-запрос:

```
SELECT id_people, MAX(id_sensor) AS last_id_sensor FROM table_name GROUP BY id_people
```

Если данный запрос возвращает неправильный результат, то, возможно, имеется проблема в данных или в структуре таблицы

Comment: а возможно, вы неправильно поняли вопрос.

Comment: Возможно, уточните пожалуйста

Comment: автору нужно не max(id_sensor) а последний `id_sensor`, то есть тот, который достигается при max(id) для юзера.

Comment: изменил ответ, теперь верно?

Comment: ... для всех юзеров, а не одного.

Comment: Всех благодарю. После долгих скитаний и совмещения ответов удалось собрать запрос, который правильно отображает результат, группирует к правильному максимальному ID.

SELECT * FROM(SELECT s.* FROM (select s.ID_PEOPLE, max(ID) as maxid from TABLE s
         group by s.ID_PEOPLE) m
         join TABLE s on s.ID_PEOPLE = m.ID_PEOPLE and s.ID = m.maxid) as t
 ORDER BY ID_PEOPLE ASC

Надеюсь этот вариант будет работать без сбоев